# Bookmarking x 2 in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In my google bookmarks I was able to hit the star button, and could choose a selection of folders that the URL could go to.  I can't work out how to do that in Chrome.  Any help would be great

Answer (score 5):

Click on the star at the end of the address bar and select a folder.

[image: bookmarking in Chrome]

Comment: If the folder you're looking for isn't in the "Folder:" dropdown, click Edit to see more choices.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, unlike Google bookmarks, does not do labelling or tagging. Only one folder per bookmark.
Consider using something that does tagging, say Xmarks or Diigo.

Comment: I am fine with putting the URL in a folder. In Google I used to be able to select more than one folder for the URL to go into, but Chrome only allows one at a time to be selected.